# Exception with thread, when calling from button in JFrame

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a timer, with threads and called it from a button and Im having a thread issue, i really do not know what is happening, when i call the method start() from the main() seems to work

this is the code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;


public class Ventana extends JFrame implements Runnable, ActionListener  {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    Thread timer = null; 
    JButton b = new JButton();
    int min,seg;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ventana v = new Ventana();
        v.setSize(400, 200);
        v.setVisible(true);

        v.setResizable(false);
//      v.start();
    }

    Ventana() {
        this.setLayout(null);
        label.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 20);
        label.setBackground(Color.white);
        label.setText("0:0");
        b.setBounds(0, 70, 80, 20);
        b.setText("iniciar");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        this.setTitle("Timer");
        this.add(label);
        this.add(b);
        this.pack();
    }

    private synchronized void start() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        timer = new Thread(this);
        System.out.println("entro");
        for(min=0;min<10;min++) {
            for(seg=0;seg<10;seg++) {     
                try {
                    timer.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                label.setText(min + ":" + seg);     
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend elaborating a bit as to what is wrong. Just glancing at the code I can see a couple of things that will cause issues. For starters, you are calling Thread.sleep (this is a static method and should be accessed as such) on the EDT which will freeze your GUI. In addition, your run implementation is empty, and the Thread you create is never started.

Answer (score 0):

You should not implement the `start()` method of `Runnable`. Put your code inside your empty `run()` method instead.

Java will call `run` when you call `start()`

Here you can see an example from Oracle: [runthread tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how does the code override the start() method of Thread?

Comment: He's not overriding anything since his class does not extend Thread (nor should it).

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your Thread business and simplify things by using a Swing Timer. It's easy -- just create a Swing Timer and in its constructor pass in two parameters, the first an int representing the time delay between calls, and for the 2nd parameter, an ActionListener that holds the code that you want to call repeatedly. This code will be guaranteed to be called on the Swing event thread, making your life easier. You can find the Swing Timer tutorial here: [Swing Timer Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

As a side recommendation, you really don't want to use use `null` layouts and `setBounds`, not just because it proclaims your GUI as that of a newbie who doesn't know better, but more because you will have an extremely difficult time upgrading and enhancing the GUI should the need arise. For instance, it is so much easier adding one more JRadioButton to a GUI made with nested JPanels and layout managers than it is for one that uses `null` layouts. Also any null layout using component that is added to a JScrollPane simply won't scroll. Also your GUI will look terrible on all platforms other than your own. Just don't do it.